# how do I fix this "error: cannot find symbol" in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Passcode 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.printf("%5s","What is the password\n");    // ask user what the code is// 

        String flake= StdIn.readString();// take in input from user// 

        String cake= "cookie"; // not complete yet but will use this in an if statement// 

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the complete stacktrace, and also the complete class include package & imports (the error could be in there).

Comment: It would probably help if you told us what symbol it can't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `StdIn.readString` in your program is from an external package. Probably from Princeton's java package?

If so, you should:

1. import the package at the beginning. For example,

   > import abc.def.StdIn;
2. add the jar package's directory you use to `CLASSPATH`. You may find a lot of useful information on how do do this on google.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have something missing with your import statements. You might wanna try the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Passcode 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.printf("%5s","What is the password\n");    // ask user what the code is// 

        //String flake= StdIn.readString();// take in input from user// 
        String flake = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(flake);

        String cake= "cookie"; // not complete yet but will use this in an if statement// 

    }
}
```